# Novel involving a girl and her sister with powers (at least one over death), invited to join people with other powers

Tags: story-identification, novel, powers

I read this somewhere in the last five years, albeit only the first few chapters. The protagonist (high school age, I think) lived with her younger sister, no parents for reasons I can't quite place. They both have powers. I think the older sister had some sort of death touch. I keep going back and forth about whether it sickened and killed them, or they died under more natural/accidental circumstances. Her younger sister, I think, had the ability to bring dead animals to life, maybe also people, with their pet actually having been resurrected. I think the death touch requires skin contact, which leads to the older girl being very antisocial and always wearing gloves. After an altercation in a parking lot with someone from the high school, she's approached by a boy her age who invites her to join his family, who all have preternatural powers. I don't think the powers are common in the population, and I think most people were unaware of them.

Unfortunately, I don't remember a ton about the other people in the house other than that it was headed up by an older gentleman and there were at least one boy and one girl already there, teenagers. I also don't remember anything about whether it was a paperback or a hardbook, or a cover (which makes me kind of wonder if I read this online, or via Kindle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the course of writing the question, I did a few more Google searches for relevant terms, and wound up with *[Cursed](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11945589-cursed)* by Jennifer R. Armentrout.

[image: Front cover of Cursed]

> Dying sucks
> ...and high school senior Ember McWilliams knows firsthand.
>
> After a fatal car accident, her gifted little sister brought her back. Now anything Ember touches dies. And that, well, really blows.
>
> Ember operates on a no-touch policy with all living things--including boys. When Hayden Cromwell shows up, quoting Oscar Wilde and claiming her curse is a gift, she thinks he's a crazed cutie. But when he tells her he can help control it, she's more than interested. There's just one catch: Ember has to trust Hayden's adopted father, a man she's sure has sinister reasons for collecting children whose abilities even weird her out. However, she's willing to do anything to hold her sister's hand again. And hell, she'd also like to be able to kiss Hayden. Who wouldn't?
>
> But when Ember learns the accident that turned her into a freak may not've been an accident at all, she's not sure who to trust. Someone wanted her dead, and the closer she gets to the truth, the closer she is to losing not only her heart, but her life.

What eventually got me the right book was a search for `novel sister "death touch"` and clicking through the results.

Following up on this, I'm listening to the audiobook. She was approached by Hayden before the parking lot altercation, which involved an ex-boyfriend turned bully and her hands are largely clean in that he only got zapped because he was assaulting her, trying to pull her shirt off (in the supermarket parking lot) to take pictures of her scars (from the car accident) to post online.