# Book about a girl who cannot touch people

Tags: story-identification, books

The book was about a girl or perhaps princess who could not either touch people or be touched. Then later she meets a boy and they fall in love then accidentally end up touching but nothing ends up happening. It was set sometime in the past I believe royal-esque times. It is not *[Shatter Me](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10429045-shatter-me)*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the cover or any other art?  Do you mean she was incapable of touching others, or just that it was not permitted?  Also, monarchies existed from before the mediaeval era through the Renaissance up to the age of Enlightenment; these are radically different societies; what are you looking for?

Comment: Honorary mention of *Cursed* by Jennifer R. Armentrout, as per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238341/novel-involving-a-girl-and-her-sister-with-powers-at-least-one-over-death-inv, although that one is set in contemporary times, and with no royalty.

Answer (score 11):

Among this fairly common trope, a partial match is *The Sin Eater's Daughter* (2015) by Melinda Salisbury.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21936988-the-sin-eater-s-daughter):

> Sixteen-year-old Twylla lives in the castle. But although she's engaged to the prince, no one speaks to her. No one even looks at her. Because Twylla isn't a member of the court. She's the executioner. As the goddess-embodied, Twylla kills with a single touch. So each week, she's taken to the prison and forced to lay her hands on those accused of treason. No one will ever love her. Who could care for a girl with murder in her veins? Even the prince, whose royal blood supposedly makes him immune to her touch, avoids her.
>
> But then a new guard arrives, a boy whose playful smile belies his deadly swordsmanship. And unlike the others, he's able to look past Twylla's executioner robes and see the girl, not the goddess. Yet a treasonous romance is the least of Twylla's problems. The queen has a plan to destroy her enemies-a plan that requires an unthinkable sacrifice. Will Twylla do what it takes to protect her kingdom? Or will she abandon her duty in favor of a doomed love?

What matches:

- Medieval times
- The girl is not a princess, but is betrothed to the prince
- She falls in love with a boy she doesn't harm, as per [this review](https://recaptains.co.uk/2017/07/the-sin-eaters-daughter-by-melinda-salisbury/):

> Lief kisses Twylla to prove that she can touch people without killing them. Seems a bit drastic. He then asks her to marry him and suggests they run away together.

Not a match:

- The girl discovering her touch doesn't affect the guard does not seem to be an incident.

---

Found with the Google query `fantasy book girl can't touch people site:goodreads.com`, deep down the sixth page of results.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? It looks like a good match to me.

Comment: Given the amount of effort required to plough through six pages of Google results (I usually give up if the answer isn't on the first page :-) downvoting seems a pretty contemptible thing to do.

Comment: Sorry, I suspect I tapped the wrong thing on my tablet. Just noticed a week later!